# Amarok doesn't start after qt4-related ubuntu updates (from raring-updates)

Tags: 13.04, updates, qt, amarok, stable-release-updates

Last Monday I updated my Ubuntu 13.04 and there were a bunch of qt4 related updates. (I don't know how to have a list of the updated packages which isn't taking a screenshot of Ubuntu Software Center "History" tab and I can't yet attach pictures)

After this update Amarok (version 2.7.0-0ubuntu2.1) is not working anymore, after it starts I can see the main windows for less than a second and then it closes.
Running amarok from terminal I get

```
The program 'amarok' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 3099 error_code 3 request_code 20 minor_code 0)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

I had already experienced this problem after updating from the repository "raring-proposed" but I managed to revert that change and disabled that repository. Unfortunately now the updates are from the raring-updates repo, and I wouldn't like to disable that!
Am I the only one experiencing this problem? I tried removing all the amarok and kde config files but it doesn't help.

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone who'd like to contribute.

Comment: [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157427](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157427) 
I found this on the ubuntu forum, however that doesn't solve the problem for me, but it looks like it's some kind of bug

Comment: [http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/amarok-startet-nach-dist-upgrade-nicht-mehr/](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/amarok-startet-nach-dist-upgrade-nicht-mehr/) Here it's someone else with my problem, no solution yet :(

Comment: It's not just Amarok.  konsole recently started crashing on me with `BadWindow` (on two different machines).  Many people are having BadWindow problems with KDevelop as well -- see [bug #1178843](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1178843).